# Is Peter related to Regina in the origin world?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

In S03E08 of *Dark*, it is revealed that:

> Regina is the daughter of Claudia and **Bernt Doppler** (from the photo above fireplace)

Now, Helge Doppler used to be the father of Peter Doppler who is turn the son of Bernt Doppler and Greta Doppler. So, that makes:

> Regina to be Peter's aunt.

Am I right? Is Peter related to Regina?

---

Now, there can be a slight discrepancy:

> Helge Doppler was the son of Bernd and Greta Doppler according to fandom. But in the official *Dark* website, there is a mention of a third person (Anatol Veilev) with whom Greta bore a child which turns out to be Helge. If Anatol exists in the origin world and the same situation happens there, Regina would become a half-aunt of Peter (not sharing blood).

Am I right? Is Peter related to Regina in the origin world, too?

Comment: Is there a way you can [edit] the question to not have so many spoilers in it, ask in a different way somehow? It's an ongoing series and it looks like you're watching it, so maybe you can also just rewatch some episodes back?

Comment: No @Luciano, I have finished watching it. I have hidden the relevant information in spoilers so that users who haven't finished the series won't get spoiled. Also, this is the only way I can ask. There is no other way. It is direct question.

Comment: I tried to ask an actual question outside of the spoiler blocks. Please try to make sure that your question makes sense even when leaving out the hidden parts. Don't worry too much about spoilers in the question body, whoever reads this question already knows that it will contain spoilers, so less spoiler blocks are usually better than more.

Comment: I think the question title is a pretty massive spoiler. _Origin World_ wasn't mentioned till the very end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the discrepancy you pointed out shows why they are *not* related.

I cannot think of a single instance in the show where the same child was born with different parents in another one of the worlds.  Everyone who has a child together seems to have the same child, whether in Martha/Eve's or Jonas/Adam's world.  This makes some sense, since a child is a combination of both parents (ignoring the *extremely* unlikely biology of having identical children in loops).

By this standard, I think we have to accept the Dark website when it suggests that Helge is not actually Bernd's son, and that this should also apply in the origin world.  This would mean that although Peter is Helge's son, Helge isn't actually Bernd's son, so there is no blood relationship between Peter and Regina.

I think the accepted answer misses the mark by suggesting that Bernd Doppler is not Regina's father, *especially* in the Origin world.  In fact, the last scene strongly implies the opposite.  At around 1:04:00 in the episode, we go to a scene in what appears to be Regina's house (Jonas/Martha's houses in their respective worlds).  It zooms in on this picture:

[image: Regina, Bernd and Claudia]

Which appears to be a family photo with Regina, Claudia and Bernd.  To me, especially based on the posture in the picture, suggests that they are a family, and Regina is Bernd's daughter.  It definitely seems to imply some relationship between Claudia and Bernd.

Comment: Well, to me, that picture feels more Regina, Claudia and her mentor (more fatherly). That's the problem, it can be concluded either ways. Other than that, all their conversations are pure business.

Comment: As the series came to an end and all knots have been untied, it is safe to assume that Bernt, Claudia and Regina is now a happy sound family in origin world.

Comment: @MovieMe Considering that we are given the shot in the same way we are shown other family photos in the same house, I think it would be _extremely_ misleading for them to include it if they weren't implying it was a family photo.  I'm pretty sure focusing on the family picture when we enter that house in every world was a common practice.  We see the same thing with the Kahnwalds and the Nielsens in their respective worlds in that house.

Comment: @NilayGhosh, that is correct. But the question you raised is about Peter and Regina's relationship. That can't be answered without establishing if Bernt is indeed Helge's father. The series does not give any closure there and hence there can't be a definite answer. Your question was never about Claudia and Brent's relationship.

Comment: @JMac, based on other photos I see the same relationship in the photo as we see between Michael and Ines, who's holding him lovingly. In any case, the Bernt Claudia relationship is not relevant to main plot as such.

Comment: @MovieMe The Bernd/Claudia relationship actually winds up being pretty relevant...  It appears to be the reason that Claudia is able to save Regina in the first place, which is pretty much the reason the loop was broken.  Claudia explains to Tronte that it's better that she's not his son, even if she might have wanted that too.  It seems like everything in the show is pretty clearly pointing to Claudia and Bernd having Regina.  The show relies a lot on getting information that isn't fully told to us explicitly in the show, this seems like an obvious case.  The official site is even explicit.

Comment: The official website even shows Tronte as the father _until_ you set it to S3 E08 spoilers, then it changes to Bernd.  It seems pretty obvious that the show tried to mislead it as Tronte+Claudia until the reveal in E08 that Regina was actually outside the loop and Tronte was never the father.

Comment: @JMac - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110015/how-could-claudia-know-of-this. I have a whole other issue with how Claudia could have known so much about the Origin World.

Comment: @MovieMe I think that's a whole other problem that I haven't seen great answers to yet.  The Regina being Bernd's daughter part though... that she already knew in her world.  She just didn't know the significance until she _somehow_ pieced together how the Origin world worked.  I saw one video trying to explain it, but it weirdly assumed she knew Tannhaus' family died in a car crash.

Answer (score 1):

Both Peter and Regina are not born of the knot. The fact that they exist in the real world and in the knotted universes means that their family trees have to be the same in the real world and knotted worlds.

There are then 4 theoretical possiblities.

Option 1)
Regina is Bernt's daughter. 
Helge is Bernt's son.
This makes Regina and Peter related.

Option 2)
Regina is **not** Bernt's daughter.
Helge is Bernt's son.
This makes Regina and Peter not related.

Option 3)
Regina is Bernt's daughter.
Helge is **not** Bernt's son.
This makes Regina and Peter not related.

Option 4)
Regina is **not** Bernt's daughter.
Helge is **not** Bernt's son.
This makes Regina and Peter not related.

The series provides no solid evidence to say if Bernt is the father of either Helge or Regina.

Assuming that each of the Options are equally possible, the highest changes that Peter and Regina are related is 1 in 4.

In short, there is a small possibility that the two are related, but it appears that the changes are really low.

Comment: The show definitely shows some clues... like the final scene in the origin world with what appears to be a [family portrait with Claudia, Bernd and Regina.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXL7s.png)  There's also the official Dark website the OP links which says that Helge is not Bernd's son.  That seems like a pretty solid source, and agrees with Martha's family tree; which only seems to get Regina's father wrong as a misdirection by Claudia.

Comment: You're right. Which is why I mentioned the "series" provides no "solid" evidence. Additional material on websites etc tend to be extrapolating in nature. E.g. LOTR. But going based on just the episodes, that picture doesn't say anything conclusively. That said, the Helge side of things still can't be concluded. Both need to be Bernt's children for any relation between Regina and Peter.

Comment: This is not how probabilities work. Eg: I am human or I am an alien, so a 50% chance I am an alien.

Comment: At some point Greta Doppler confesses to Noah that she did not want Helge. I am not sure if she gives a reason, but chronologically Helge was concieved towards the end of WWII. At this time IRL a lot of German women were raped and a lot of them were forced to prostitute themselves just to survive. If Helge was the product of rape or prostitution it would fit in with Greta's extremely cold attitude towards him.

Comment: @ivana, I'm aware of probability calculations. It's not rocket science. For sake of simplicity I assumed each option is equally probable. The point is not the calculation. One could speculate to any extent, in spite of what you say, or what denominator you choose to calculate the probability, the fact remains that there is no concrete answer to this question. Any speculation could be wrong. That's the point. Greta doesn't confesses. She "thinks" he was born of sin. She didn't know for sure.

Comment: @Ivana .. what you are saying only makes Option 3 and 4 even less probable, making the overall probability go down even further. It only amplifies the fact that Peter and Regina are not related. That Greta was raped is nothing more than a guess based on general history, as long as it's guesswork, its probability is still 0.5 . We're shown nothing about Greta's past, for all you know... she might be mentally unstable and Helge is actually Bernt's son and she's just a terrible mother.

Answer (score 0):

### Unlikely

Claudia's interactions with Bernt revolve around her working for Bernt in (and eventually succeeding him as the boss of) the nuclear power plant. The origin world is shown to not have a power plant, suggesting that the source of Claudia and Bernt's interactions never existed in the origin world.

That doesn't exclude that they knew each other via another way, but it's quite unlikely, or at the very least completely unexplored.

Additionally:

- We simply do not get any information from the origin world except in relation to Tanhauss' family and what we can infer from the dinner party in the end. It's impossible to know which facts carry over to the origin world.
- Even in Adam's world, it's only a rumor that Bernt fathered Regina, it hasn't actually been confirmed.

Comment: Please confirm my [interpretation](https://imgur.com/OhCpP0H). 1. It was not confirmed that Helge was an unwanted son of Greta. She confessed to Noah that she just believed that he was an unwanted son (S1E9). So, Bernt becomes grandfather of Peter. 2. We don't know father of Regina in Adam's word. It may be Bernt or Tronte based on rumors, so no connection between Regina and Peter in Adam's world. 3. In origin world, maybe Anatol became husband of Greta and subsequently became grandfather of Peter (speculation). So, no connection between Regina and Peter in any way.

Comment: The family tree on http://darknetflix.io confirms that Bernd Doppler is the father of Regina in both Adam’s world and Eve’s world, so I think he’s still the father of Regina in the origin world. I don’t think people ever change parents in different worlds.

Comment: @NilayGhosh: If you assume Helge is not Bernt's son, then there is no relation between Peter and Regina regardless of whether Bernt is Regina's father (unless Helge's real father is somehow related to Regina and/or Bernt, which we have no reason to assume)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Exactly.  I don't see how it's possible to suggest anyone else is the father if Regina is literally the daughter of Bernd and Regina in every instance we see.  It wouldn't make sense to have the same child through different sets of parents.

Comment: I just remembered another detail that basically confirms that Bernd and Claudia have a relationship in the Origin world.  In the final scene, we are shown what appears to be one of the [family portraits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXL7s.png) that the show often gives us.  This one shows Bernd, Claudia and Regina together, in the origin world.  Bernd and Claudia appear to be very well acquainted in the picture.