# How could Claudia know of this?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

In the series DARK, Claudia tells Adam in the end that she spent 33 years toggling between the two worlds that are knotted together. That both these worlds must be an ulcer created from a third Origin World. Based on her assessment of Regina's parentage, she figures that Regina is not bootstrapped and therefore must be present in the Origin World, alive and well.

But from there she also goes on to talk about how H.G. Tannhaus makes the mistake of building a time device and destroying the Origin World in the 1986 and giving birth to the two knotted worlds. In the knotted worlds, H.G. Tannhaus is mysteriously given a bootstrapped baby Charlotte and because of that he doesn't obsess over his dead son and family.

My question is: 
How could Claudia from Adam's World gain the knowledge of Tannhaus' time device incident and date in the Origin World, given she has access only to knotted worlds which don't give any clue about the parent Origin World?

Comment: I haven't seen a great answer on this either.  We do know a few things she could piece together with some research and her science knowledge, like the existence of the exploitable loophole.  I've always wondered if there's a bunch of hints to the real world on rewatch.  One thing that always seemed suspicious to me is that the loop created a Charlotte, who winds up as Tannhaus' adopted daughter/granddaughter, and Origin Tannhaus was trying to save his granddaughter Charlotte.

Comment: That's correct. I too would peg that as the real Origin of the knotted chaos. But beyond that she couldn't have guessed the whole H.G. Tannhaus creating a time device which fires 16 years after the death of the son. Claudia gets to somehow follow this Origin World's H.G Tannhaus for that period of time to understand the connection to the knotted worlds. :|

Comment: @JMac: I suspect the Charlotte name is (a) Tannhaus' decision as he pretends as if his adopted daughter is still his real daughter (for administrative purposes) and (b) Elisabeth names her daughter Charlotte after her own mother, to honor her after she went missing in the apocalypse. Keep in mind that "new mom" Elisabeth does not know that her daughter will be taken from her, she doesn't name her child Charlotte because she e.g. knows that the child will grow up to be Charlotte (her mother).

Comment: @Flater I was never implying that.  What I meant was that Claudia might have been able to recognize that the two worlds that got created essentially made a replacement "Charlotte" for Tannhaus; which probably could have stood out when she realized that Tannhaus just lost his Charlotte and was delivered a baby (from the time loop) on the same day.

Comment: I'd reckon that Claudia looked into the mysterious blast of nuclear energy that created the Boson in 1986. Both worlds had this happen on the same date. Both worlds had a leak and Claudia would have realized the leak was caused by the unknown. So she would go back to understanding the energy blast. Given she knew her quantum science (Boson) .. I guess she *somehow* concluded that the blast originated from a third world. The nature of blast being identical also suggests a single origin? Maybe. After this... the script writers really need to fill in :)

Comment: @JMac That exploitable loophole is the mother of all problems with the ending of dark. Quantum Entanglement was beautifully used to explain altered events through alternate Jonas and Martha... up until there were two of them. But that same loophole was used to also save Marek. Which should naturally mean Marek both exists and doesn't. Meaning all three wolds exist and dont exist. Even the official Netflix explainer video makes fun of this :D. I think we should just conclude that Claudia had an elaborate dream in the OW!

Answer (score -2):

Part of this is inference on Claudia's behalf. She was exceptionally clever to figure it out. It wasn't easy to figure this out and the evidence is few and far between.

However, it's important to realize that the knotted worlds were created after Tannhaus' family died, since origin-Tannhaus does so after Marek, Sonja and Charlotte were killed).
That means that both Adam-Tannhaus and Eva-Tannhaus have also lost their family.

The same applies to essentially everything that happened in the Origin world before Tannhaus created the knot.

When you compare Adam and Eve's worlds, some things match and some things don't.

- The things that don't match all originate from the Unknown in some way.
- The things that do match are facts that carried over from the Origin world.

You can start making a few educated guesses here. If both Adam-Tannhaus and Eve-Tannhaus lost their family and delved deep into the idea of time travel, then Origin-Tannhaus is likely to have done the same. Especially if you find out that he was already into it before his family got killed (since Marek himself throws it in his face in the series finale).

We don't know Claudia's full thought proces. We just see her explain what she already knows to Adam, she doesn't explain how she found it out.

But given the cyclical nature of events, and the bootstrapping done by (old) Claudia constantly transferring her complete knowledge to (middle age) Claudia, that means that Claudia essentially had an infinite amount of time to expand her knowledge and figure it out.

Every cycle's Claudia has 33 years of knowledge to pass to the 33-years-younger Claudia, who then in turn passes that acquired knowledge + her own 33 years of knowledge down to the next Claudia, and so on.

We have no way of knowing how many cycles there have been. It could have been millions, billions, trillions, ...

It's reasonable to assume that Claudia would at some point have a theory. Maybe she had thousands or millions of other theories that never panned out.

**We only get to see the theory that turns out to be correct.**

Comment: @Gaston nice icon ;-)

Comment: originate from the Unknown in some way - Not at all, the Tiedemanns are only one such thing.

Comment: Origin-Tannhaus is likely to have done the same. Especially if you find out that he was already into it before his family got killed - The Knotted Tannhaus only builds the time machine because of the nature of bootstrap. The tempting assumption would be to assume it would not be there in the real world. Just like how Claudia assumed that the Third World would be free of the bootstrap paradox.

Comment: "Every cycle's Claudia has 33 years of knowledge to pass to the 33-years-younger Claudia" - oh no no no no. Not at all. Any predestination causal loop is cyclical in nature only for the observer of the loop. For the loop itself. The people in the predestination loop live non linearly inside it but *never* looping on themselves over and over. This *not* Edge Of Tomorrow or Groundhog Day. Not one bit. Claudia is born, she continuously ages and eventually grows old and dies. Each thing she experiences is only once at that particular age.

Comment: A bootstrap paradox is a byproduct of the predestination paradox. If we have a multiple timeline situation (where the action of going back to the past creates a new timeline), then there is no Predestination Pardox, and no way there can be a Bootstrap Paradox. DARK much like other cinema like 12 Monkeys, Predestination, Time Crimes establishes a Predestination Loop. Cinena where loops repeat like Groundhog Day or Palm Springs has an entirely different premise. The Bootstrap Paradox wouldn't exist in that set up as things reset. It's a rewind and replay situation. DARK is not rewind and reply.

Comment: @MovieMe: Each Claudia only experiences her own life but two Claudias can exchange information. This is no different from Adam giving Jonas information, which also happens. The reason I focus on Claudia and not Jonas is that she's the one who spent her lifetime(s) improving her knowledge, whereas Adam spent it maintaining the status quo.

Comment: @MovieMe: A predestination paradox inherently relies on things not changing (people's lives are _predestined_, i.e. set in stone. What has happened will always have happened), but Dark specifically resolves it plot by pointing out that cycles can change (step by step) and eventually introduce a breaking change that undoes the entire knotted universes. That is _not_ predestination. If you suggest predestination then you're suggesting the first cycle's old Claudia already figured out how to break the knot - which directly contradicts the source material in several ways.

Comment: The Predestination Paradox and Bootstrap Paradox are elements of science. They go way back. Cinema only applies these concepts to show them visually. The source material takes the name of Bootstrap Paradox quite clearly. So there is no doubt that this is a singular Predestination Loop. Even if old Claudia gives the information to young Claudia, she can do it only a finite number of times. E.g.: if each year of her life's learnings she gives it to her younger self. Assuming she lived 33 years. Then that is 33days that Claudia got information. There is no millions or infinite in Dark.

Comment: If old Claudia spent 1 year learning a piece of information, then young Claudia must also go though that path. Young Claudia, can in no way know more than Old Claudia at any point in her life. Why? Because Claudia might be in time nonlinearly, but she ages linearly. She must go though all the events her older self goes through. This includes gathering information. Else she will not reach that moment with Adam after he has killed Martha. Claudia is no exception to the predestined nature of the loop. We are shown this quite clearly. There is no confusion in this. There is no billions of times.

Comment: @Flater, Even if Claudia wrote all the information for 33 years and gave it to her younger self, then that additional information is the result of the bootstrap paradox and will happen a total of *one* time. This is exactly like how the information in the notebook or the blueprints for the time machine. But that still doesn't explain how she could jump to a conclusion about the exact date Tannhaus turned on his "mystery"machine in the OW. Remember, she herself could not visit the OW. IMO that's still a very big gap which can be filled with just about anything *and* nothing ;)

Comment: _Dark specifically resolves it plot by pointing out that cycles can change_
I think think there are too many things wrong with what the answer is proposing. Apart from the fact that there is no infinite loop that any person is experiencing, there are a total of *two* outcomes. (1) The OW is destroyed and the two worlds exist within a predestination paradox with one set of events, and *only* those. (2) The OW is saved which leads to the alteration and therefore the destruction of the two worlds. That's it. There is no *step by step change* and no one is reliving their lives over and over.

Comment: @atm: You're forgetting about the Claudia/Adam conversation where Claudia specifically points out that she has been using the time freeze (i.e. that fraction of a second during the apocalypse) to make minor changes to an otherwise fixed causality chain, and then urges Adam to repeat the cycle and "get back" to this point so they can change it further. The cycles have been different, in subtle ways, as an attempt by Claudia to edge closer to a state in which it is possible to break the cycles. That's not a guess from me, that's Claudia's own words.

Comment: @Flater, au contraire mon ami, Claudia says just the opposite. _But just like you and Eva I had to preserve everything in order to become what I am today so that my path could lead me here to you today. I know where the loophole is that you've searched for all this time. Time, during the apocalypse, it stood still for a fraction of a second.
And I used it to send myself in another direction, too to be here today. You must use it to send Jonas on a different path in order to break the cycle once and for all. You must send Martha and Jonas to the origin world, so they can finally end all this._

Comment: @Flatter .. As you can see in the dialogues above. Claudia has had two and *only* two paths. One that leads to her death at the hands of Noah. And one that leads her to Adam. She has *not* been doing this indefinitely. Adam too goes on to use that loophole *one* time. In that he creates a Third Jonas that ends the knot. I have no idea where you got the slightest idea that she's been making minor alterations. It's a fixed causal loop with quantum entanglement allowing for 3 Jonas, 3 Marthas and 2 Claudias. And that's it. No re-looping.

Comment: @atm: Claudia says _"Thing may not happen in the same way or at the same time, but they do happen."_ Some eventualities cannot be avoided, but changes **can be** (and are) made as to how they come about.

Comment: @atm: Adam _presumably_ uses the loophole one time, causing Jonas and Martha to undo the know (we don't know for sure, and even Claudia says that she **thinks** that this is the first time Adam and her have this conversation - not even Claudia is sure). But Claudia has changed many things in many cycles before she was able to get to that point. To Claudia, there's only "Regina dies" vs "Regina lives" (her goal), but there are actually many intermediate "Regina dies" realities which are all necessary for her to finally get to the point where she can create the "Regina lives" outcome.

Comment: @Flater, again, no. You're quoting half a dialogue to make your point work. The full dialogue is _There is no difference between the two worlds. Things may not happen in the same way, or at the same time. But they do happen_ Claudia is talking about how things may not happen in the same way in comparison *between* the two worlds. Example, Ulrich is divorced vs not.

Comment: What do you mean by “The things that don't match all originate from the Unknown in some way.”?  It seems to me that the differences between Adam’s world and Eve’s world originate from Mikkel being conceived earlier in Eve’s world, leading him to be old enough not to need a babysitter on November 4, 2019, leading him not going to the caves and not time traveling.  What does The Unknown have to do with any of the differences?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: You're comparing the differences between Adam's world and Eve's world. I'm comparing the Origin world to the differences found in Adam and/or Eve's world.

Comment: Well, you said “When you compare Adam and Eve's worlds, some things match and some things don't. The things that don't match all originate from the Unknown in some way.  The things that do match are facts that carried over from the Origin world.”  So it sounds like you’re saying that when Adam’s world and Eve’s world have a common feature, that comes from the Origin world.  And when Adam’s world and Eve’s world has a difference, that comes from the Unknown.  Am I misreading you?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: The bullet points below the sentence you're quoting explicitly show that I was in fact referring to "comparing Adam and Eve's worlds [to the Origin world]".